# Use JSON_EXTRACT in WHERE condition

Tags: javascript, mysql

How to add condition base on a value in JSON field , I am able find all data with

```
 SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(transaction_data, "$.giftshop_product_data.matrix_product_id") from user_transactions order by created_at desc;
```

But JSON_EXTRACT not working in where clouse

```
SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(transaction_data, "$.giftshop_product_data.matrix_product_id") from user_transactions where JSON_EXTRACT(transaction_data, "$.giftshop_product_data.matrix_product_id") = "133" order by created_at desc;
```

Error

> Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function
>   json_extract: "Missing a closing quotation mark in string." at
>   position 26.